# Can the castor oil plant (Ricinus communis) build up toxicity in my soils?

Tags: soil, toxicity

I am doing some experimentation with [*Ricinus communis*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Castor_oil_plant), which I know contains the toxin Ricin. Through my own experience and research I am not concerned with interacting with the plant or touching it. Do I need to worry about a build-up of toxicity in my soil?

I have tried to research the topic, but my knowledge of chemistry isn't enough to be able to understand the information I am getting back. This chemical formulation should just decompose back into available non-toxic organic matter, right?

Comment: Is there something you would like me to add to my answer?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, it will break down. The toxin [ricin](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ricin) is a type of [protein](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Protein) called a [lectin](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lectin), which is [disabled by carbohydrates](http://www.krispin.com/lectin.html), specifically [mono-](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monosaccharide) and [oligosaccharides](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oligosaccharide). And even if there is some in your soil, don't worry. [Plants don't uptake protein](http://www.eurohydro.com/pdf/articles/gb_plant-food4.pdf) [(second source)](http://www.ias.ac.in/resonance/Volumes/03/07/0045-0052.pdf) through their roots, so you won't have to worry if you grow food crops in the same area you are growing castor beans.